# Issue with marker hiding when add_last_point is set to False

Tags: python-3.x, geojson, folium

When `add_last_point=True` I see two markers as expected but when I set `add_last_point=False`, the marker disappears completely.

Relevant bit of code.

```py
features = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    coordinates = [row['longitude'], row['latitude']]
    feature = {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'LineString',
            'coordinates': [[row['latitude'], row['longitude']]]  # LineString needs at least two points
        },
        'properties': {
            'time': row['timestamp'],
            "icon": "marker",
            "iconstyle": {
                "iconUrl": 'picture.png',
                "iconSize": [50, 50],
            }
        }
    }
    features.append(feature)

geojson_data = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': features
}

# Adding TimestampedGeoJson to the map
plugins.TimestampedGeoJson(
    geojson_data,
    period='PT1S',
    add_last_point=False,
    duration="PT1S",
    auto_play=True,
    loop=True,
    max_speed=4.0
    loop_button=True,
    time_slider_drag_update=True,
    transition_time=500,   #i sec
    date_options='YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss',
).add_to(mapObj)

# Adding PolyLine using imported data
folium.PolyLine(
    locations=df[['longitude', 'latitude']].values.tolist(),
    color="red",
    weight=4
).add_to(mapObj)
```